# SQL count number of spesific tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Database which includes several tables(like test1, test2 etc). I want to count the number of table which are beggining with a spesific keyword on table name. Such as get all tables which starts with keyword "test". Is there any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `information_schema.tables`:

```
select t.table_name, t.table_schema
from information_schema.tables t
where t.table_name like 'test%';
```

Note that this works in both MySQL and SQL Server.